# substitue part of a string using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, sh

Assume the regular expression of a email is [a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-zA-Z0-9]+, I would like to substitute all the id part into "customer", for example

mike@yahoo.com => customer@yahoo.com
john@gmail.com => customer@gmail.com

I can write something like

```
$ echo mike@yahoo.com | sed 's/[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*/customer/g'
```

But how can I get the domain part not changed? Basically, the question is find a pattern in a string and substitute just part of it and the remaining part not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture parts of the matched pattern with `\(..\)` and reuse it in your replacement string using `\1`:

```
echo mike@yahoo.com | sed 's/[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*@\([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*\)/customer@\1/g'
```

Comment: thanks! that works. Can there be only one pair of \(,\) and referred as \1? Or can there be multiple pairs? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making it too complicated:

```
echo mike@yahoo.com | sed -e 's/.*@/customer@/'
```

Comment: If there are something like mike@, andy@, these are not valid patterns for emails.

Comment: @AlfredZhong True, but why does that matter? The part of the string not matched by `sed` will not be modified. Try it.

Comment: @AlfredZhong This is correct. `sed` will ignore the parts which aren't matched. That's what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but the requirement is that the substitution only happen on valid email patterns, something like mike@ should not be substituted. The answer by @that other guy is what I am looking for

Comment: @AlfredZhong Well, the original question did not state that, and if that's the case, then even the accepted answer is not general enough - e.g. there are valid e-mails with 3 or more sections in the domain suffix, and 2 or more in the user name, and there are characters outside of the set `[A-Za-z0-9]` that are acceptable as well (e.g. `_`)...